# MSVS Link Error for MapViewOFFIleEx

Tags: c++, user32

I have executed the following command in MSVS Native console.

```
cl -Feedgcpfex64.exe -D _WIN64 ../src/*.c user32.lib
```

and got the following linker error.

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MapViewOfFileEx@28 referenced in function _map_file_region
```

Comment: It's in kernel32.lib. Check always MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the case that you are using `32 bit native tool` command prompt. There is no need to change library name for `x64` support as `user32.lib` and `kernel32.lib` are different for `64 bit environment` but the name is same.

Comment: Yes, Using a 64 bit environment command prompt solved my problem. Thanks @shagun

Answer (score -1):

Look at the MSDN docs for the function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx

> Library - Kernel32.lib
>
> DLL - Kernel32.dll

You need to add kernel32.lib to your compiler arguments list, and it will forward that to the linker.

Comment: we don't need to link against kernel32.lib explicitly as that's already done by default by cl.exe command

Comment: The linker does linking, not cl. Default libraries are not necessarily always linked against. cl.exe can build kernel drivers, and they definitely do not have kernel32.lib. If that isn't working then my only guess is that you are targeting 32-bit yet defining _WIN64 and causing all your function prototypes to be wrong. Can you paste your full compiler command line?

Comment: The only command i am using of above in my question. and cl is able to invoke linker by itself if you pass lib files to it.